# firebase realtime database offline mode to prevent R/W limitation

Tags: python, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I heard that firebase realtime database has some limitation for free version:

```
Simultaneous connections: 100
GB stored: 1 GB
GB downloaded: 10 GB/month
Multiple databases per project: No
```

I also heard that firebase work on offline mode. I want prevent GB downloaded counted 10GB/month, therefore I expect I can setup firebase realtime database to store in local database.

Here's my basic code:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

load_dotenv()

# Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
cred = credentials.Certificate(os.getenv('FIREBASE_CREDENTIAL_PATH'))

# Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
  'databaseURL': os.getenv('FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL')
})

# As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regradless of Security Rules
ref = db.reference('/a_reference')
ref.set({
  'data':'test'
})
print(ref.get())

# ref.push() #I thought if I comment this, it will store in local database.
```

After I run code above, I got expected output. But, it also updated to the databaseURL (online) which is counting `GB Downloaded` limitation.

I expect it stored locally first before, because I want develop my entire app with db, so many R/W operations in DB while I'm debugging.

Comment: (not the downvoter) What is your question? Specifically: when you run the code you shared, what line doesn't do what you expect it to do? Is there an error message?

Comment: My question is: `How to store data locally with firebase?`

Comment: OK. Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Admin SDKs for Firebase don't support persistent offline caching of data. The Python SDK specifically is a fairly thin wrapper around Firebase's [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start), and any calls you make to the API result in direct calls to the online database.

If you want the Python client to work offline, you will have to persist the data locally yourself.